# Update Wordpress from non-public machine

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

I'm setting up a Wordpress installation on a development machine. This machine, for both technical and security machines, isn't routable from the internet. (In other words, while it can connect to the internet, it isn't possible to use SSH or HTTP to connect to it from the internet.)

Is there a way to use WP's auto-update facilities given these constraints? The update page asks for FTP credentials, which won't work because: a) the machine has no public IP address, and b) I'd have to be a fool to run an FTP server on my machine.

Comment: it's asking for ftp credentials as a fallback because it can't alter the filesystem directly, that's a permissions issue.

Comment: If you turn that into an answer, I'll accept it. It worked for me.